# Azure App Service and VNet to VNet Connectivity

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to setup an app service to connect to a SQL database on a VM in two different subscriptions. I configured the app service to use Point to Site VPN through a VNET gateway. Then configured VNET peering in both subscriptions. I still cannot connect to the database from the app service. I have verified that the network service groups configured for the VM subnet aren't the reason the connection is failing. What other configuration could I be missing?

Comment: Additional, if you'v configured your Web app with integration VNet with it , it just can be connect the VNet,but not within the VNet. What I suggest is using ASE for it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working. The problem was the second VNET wasn't configured properly to route traffic back to the P2S address range.